# Transferring a makefile using PUTTY scp

Tags: putty, scp

I've written a makefile and I am trying to send it to the folder containing the program I am trying to compile.

the command I am trying is:
scp username@host.com ~/destinationdirectory C\Users\Myname\Desktop\Makefile

the response I get is:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known
lost connection

any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

The command syntax is:

```
scp <source> user@host:destination
```

With that, you may try:

```
scp C\Users\Myname\Desktop\Makefile username@host.com:destinationdirectory/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use windows, so this might not work for you, but try the following:

`scp username@host.com:/home/username/destinationdirectory C\Users\Myname\Desktop\Makefile`

Comment: Nope, still giving me the same errors I listed in my problem description

Comment: If you are looking to upload the file to a remote server, then @gombadi's answer should be what you are looking for.